# Not able to convert applet to Jwrapper app

Tags: jwrapper

I have an applet project which loads sensor dlls and loads sensor gui in web page,using jwrapper i am able to build the project and create 2 files FutronicAppEmbed.js FutronicAppEmbed.html ,but when i am running this FutronicAppEmbed.html nothing is displayed in browser.Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you open the HTML file in a browser you won't see anything as it won't load properly but if you put all the files from your build folder on a web server and then load the FutronicAppEmbed.html page you will get a download button for the app appropriate to your operating system.

JWrapper is an alternative to applets though in that it is an app delivery system which allows you to do dynamic parameterisation (as you can with server-side generated parameters in applet pages), but its not a direct replacement for applets in that the app will load in the web page.  Instead you will need to specify a standard java main method and load your app in a swing frame and JWrapper will launch that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am able to get download button in web page but i am not able to download it, as it goes to some other location . And if i will be able to download it, will it serve as a client means like a standalone application, and session will not be maintained? I want to know that like applet the app opens in browser is it not possible in jwrapper ?

Comment: You can edit the embed HTML and change the URL to be whatever the correct URL is for the generated app JS file based on where your web server is, then it should load fine.   It depends what you mean by 'session' but if you mean the web session then session can be maintained even though its a standalone app because you can use server side code to pass the cookie or token to the app but it doesn't just work like a standard applet, its a different method of delivery that gives you the benefits of a continuous session like an applet, it doesn't display in the browser like applets.

Comment: Ok. I have an applet code I converted it into swing standalone application then referred its main file in build file. Is it fine because i saw somwhere the whole application was built using jwrapper libs. and is there any way to receive the parameters from client application to back to server .

Comment: Actually we are developing a webservice in which we needed applet to load sensor dlls and pass parameters to applet and then receive from it. for that purpose I also worked on JavaFX  as an applet replacement but in latest version of chrome its not working.so again trying with jwrapper hope ,it can help .